# Contracting tensor in Matlab

Tags: matlab, tensor

I am looking for a way to contract two indices of a tensor in Matlab.

Say I have a tensor of dimension [17,10,17,12] I am looking for a function that sums over the first and third dimension with the same index and leaves a matrix of dimension [10,12] (analogous to a trace in two dimensions).

I am currently studying tensor networks and I mainly use the functions "permute" and "reshape". If one is contracting multiple tensors and is not careful from the beginning, one might end up with indices one wants to contract in one tensor of the form [i,j,i,k].

Of course one can go back and contract the tensors in a way such that this does not happen, but I'd nonetheless be interested in a more robust solution.

EDIT:

Something to the effect of:

```
A = rand(17,10,17,12);
A_contracted = zeros(10,12);
for i = [1:10]
    for j = [1:12]
        for k = [1:17]
            A_contracted(i,j) = A_contracted(i,j) + A(k,i,k,j);
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it:

```
A_contracted = permute(sum( ...
   A.*((1:size(A,1)).'==reshape(1:size(A,3), 1, 1, [])), [1 3]), [2 4 1 3]);
```

The above uses [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) and the possibility to operate along multiple dimensions at once in [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html), which are recent Matlab features. For older Matlab versions,

```
A_contracted = permute(sum(sum( ...
   A.*bsxfun(@eq, (1:size(A,1)).', reshape(1:size(A,3), 1, 1, [])),1),3), [2 4 1 3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

[I feel like I'm starting to sound like a broken record...]

You should always implement your code as a loop first, then try to optimize using `permute` and `reshape`. But note that `permute` needs to copy data, so tends to increase the amount of work, rather than decrease it. Recent versions of MATLAB are no longer slow with loops, and thus copying data is no longer always a useful hack to speed up things.

For example, the loop in the question can be simplified to:

```matlab
A_contracted = zeros(size(A,2),size(A,4));
for k = 1:size(A,1)
    A_contracted = A_contracted + squeeze(A(k,:,k,:));
end
```

(I've also generalized to arbitrary sizes).

Comparing with [Luis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55904552/7328782), I see the vectorized method winning for small arrays such as the one in the OP (17x10x17x12) with 0.09 ms vs 0.19 ms. But with very small times all around it is likely not worth the effort. However, for larger arrays (I tried 17x100x17x120) I see the loop method winning 1.3 ms vs 2.6 ms.

The more data, the bigger the advantage to using just plain old loops. With 170x100x170x120 it is 0.04 s vs 0.45 s.

---

Test code:

```matlab
A = rand(17,100,17,120);
assert(all(method2(A)==method1(A),'all'))
timeit(@()method1(A))
timeit(@()method2(A))

function A_contracted = method1(A)
A_contracted = permute(sum( ...
   A.*((1:size(A,1)).'==reshape(1:size(A,3), 1, 1, [])), [1 3]), [2 4 1 3]);
end

function A_contracted = method2(A)
A_contracted = zeros(size(A,2),size(A,4));
for k = 1:size(A,1)
    A_contracted = A_contracted + squeeze(A(k,:,k,:));
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My professor suggested another solution (in the following denoted by method3) involving reshape and matrix multiplication.

1. take a unit matrix of the size of the contracted index
2. reshape it into a vector
3. reshape the tensor you want to contract accordingly
4. multiply the vector and the tensor
5. reshape the Contracted tensor

sample code comparing to [Luis's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55904552/10077730) (method1) and [Cris's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55906664/10077730) answer (method2):

```
A = rand(17,10,17,10);

timeit(@()method1(A))
timeit(@()method2(A))
timeit(@()method3(A))

function A_contracted = method1(A)
A_contracted = permute(sum( ...
   A.*((1:size(A,1)).'==reshape(1:size(A,3), 1, 1, [])), [1 3]), [2 4 1 3]);
end


function A_contracted = method2(A)
A_contracted = zeros(size(A,2),size(A,4));
for k = 1:size(A,1)
    A_contracted = A_contracted + squeeze(A(k,:,k,:));
end
end


function A_contracted = method3(A)
sa_1 = size(A,1);
Unity = eye(size(A, 1));
Unity = reshape(Unity, [1,sa_1*sa_1]);
A1 = permute(A, [1,3,2,4]);
A2 = reshape(A1, [sa_1*sa_1, size(A1, 3)* size(A1,4)]);
UnA = Unity*A2;
A_contracted = reshape(UnA, [size(A1,3), size(A1,4)]);
end
```

method3 dominates for small dimensions by an order of magnitude over both method1 and method2 and beats method1 for larger dimensions as well, but is beaten by for loops for larger dimensions by one order of magnitude.

method3 has the (somewhat personal) advantage of being more intuitive for the application in my physics course in the sense that a contraction is not really in the tensor itself, but with respect to a metric. method3 may be easily adapted to incorporate this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy

```
squeeze(sum(sum(a,3),1))
```

The `sum(a,n)` sums over the nth dimension of the array and the `squeeze` removes any singleton dimensions

Comment: I've edited the question. I believe that what you propose sums over the indices independently, but not in in the same step. I've just tried it in and it does not give the desired result.

Comment: @Phteven You should add a small example, and the desired output. The proposed answer is correct for your initial question: _I am looking for a function that sums over the first and third index and leaves a matrix of dimension [5,3]._ Unfortunately, your edit is no proper MATLAB code, and it remains unclear, what you really want to achieve. Also, your edit invalidates the given (correct) answer, so that later readers might think, this answer is (or was) wrong from the beginning.

Comment: @user1543042
I am sorry about this. The code I've added now works for my example. The answer is of course correct for the ill posed question but not my problem.